# How do I set multiple cookies with CherryPy

Tags: python, cookies, cherrypy

From CherryPy [documentation](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/progguide/cookies.html), there seems to be only one cookie slot. Here's my example code

```
def sendCookie(self):
    cookie = cherrypy.response.cookie
    cookie['name'] = 'Chips Ahoy!'
    return 'Cookie is now in your hands.'
sendCookie.exposed = True
```

I want to set multiple cookies. I'm thinking along these lines, but of course this will just overwrite the first setting.

```
def sendCookie(self):
    cookie = cherrypy.response.cookie
    cookie2 = cherrypy.response.cookie
    cookie['name'] = 'Chips Ahoy!'
    cookie2['name'] = 'Chocolate Chips'
    return 'Cookie is now in your hands.'
sendCookie.exposed = True
```

How do I set multiple cookies with CherryPy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the first key in `cookie` should correspond to the name of the cookie, where additional keys would correspond to attributes of that cookie. Thus, instead of using `'name'` as the key for your cookies, you should use some unique name.

```
def sendCookie(self):
    cookies = cherrypy.response.cookie

    cookies['cookie1'] = 'Chips Ahoy!'
    cookies['cookie1']['path'] = '/the/red/bag/'
    cookies['cookie1']['comment'] = 'round'

    cookies['cookie2'] = 'Chocolate Chips'
    cookies['cookie2']['path'] = '/the/yellow/bag/'
    cookies['cookie2']['comment'] = 'thousands'

    return 'Cookies are now in your hands.'
setCookie.exposed = True
```

Does that work?

Edit: Oops, each [`morsel`](http://docs.python.org/library/cookie.html#Cookie.Morsel) has a predefined set of properties, where I was defining my own (`'shape'` and `'count'`). Should be fixed now.

Comment: No, only one cookie gets set. In this case, only `cookie2`. `cookie1` is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Oops sorry. It's all good. I was testing on a non-secure http and I set my first cookie to be `secure` :)

Comment: Hmm, OK. According to [this page](http://blog.eddsn.com/2010/05/how-to-use-cookies-with-cherrypy/) you need to send `'max-age'` or `'expires'` for each cookie as well. If that doesn't work, I'm afraid I'm out of ideas. :/